# Yii2 - hasMany cause Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, has-many

In `gridView` I want to show delete button if the `service` doesn't have any
records in `calls` table.

But I get this error (because the array is very big?):

> yii\base\ErrorException: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Table **calls** (with 283365 records)

```
id, number, name, id_service
```

Table **service**

```
id, name
```

**common/models/Service.php**

```
public function getCalls()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Calls::className(), ['id_service' => 'id']);
}
```

**gridView**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

       'id',
       'id_service',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
           'template' => '{delete}',
           'visibleButtons' => [
             'delete' => function ($model) {
               return !$model->calls;
                       // !isset($model->calls[0]->id) //same problem
              }
           ],
       ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Try `return !$model->getCalls()->exists();`. This will result n+1 queries problem, but at least it should work.

Comment: @rob006 it's working! I didn't know this function. thanks!